# Can't set default select value in ReactiveForms , Angular 7

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular2-changedetection

I have some problem with changeDetection as Angular doesnt update my reactive control value into the dropdown view.

I have reproduced the full problem in a simple  **[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown-setvalue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown%2Fdropdown.component.ts)**  .

*So basically how can i force Angular to show me 'Argentina' as selected default option in dropdown ?*

Would be very grateful if anyone give me a hint how to solve this

Comment: `{
      "id": 5,
      "text": "Argentina"
  }` is not part of your `this.definitions` array?

Comment: no, is it possible to set data outside of  this.definitions array ?

Comment: No, you cant. You have to include it as part of this.defintions.

Comment: I have added my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the the select options list does not contain that particular data you are trying to select.

In your case, `{ "id": 5, "text": "Argentina" }` should be part of `this.definitions` too.

You can either push that object to `this.definitions` before declaring your reactive form,

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
  this.definitions.push(this.default);
  this.rootFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    control: this.default
  });
```

Or, you explicity include that object on this.definitions when you are writing your code.

```
definitions = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Poland"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "UK"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "Germany"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "text": "France"
    },
    { 
      "id": 5, 
      "text": "Argentina" 
    }

  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the `{ "id": 5, "text": "Argentina" }` object in the definitions array you are binding to the select tag. Without adding the object you cant bind the value.

```
definitions = [
    { 
      "id": 5, 
      "text": "Argentina" 
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Poland"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "UK"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "Germany"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "text": "France"
    }
  ]
```